# Twitter search API not returning tweet images

Tags: python, json, api, twitter

I have implemented the Twitter search api successfully, and am retrieving data in the exact way shown here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets

The issue is that for tweets which contain uploaded images, I'm not getting those image urls in my JSON data. I do see the media URLs for quoted or re-tweeted tweets, but never for the original tweet itself, which I find very strange.

There is no documentation about media related parameters in the API guide either, but I'm sure there is a way to retrieve images.

I am using the `python-twitter` module.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Twitter docs are severely lacking. I added `&tweet_mode=extended` and a lot more data including media related params popped up.